# How to conditionally disable an object within an array in Angular

Tags: angularjs, indexof

I have several select elements on the same page. Each select dropdown contains the same items. I would like to disable an item within the dropdown if it has already been selected in another select element. In other words, I don't want an item to be selected more than once across all of the select elements.

Any thoughts on how to accomplish this?

When I use the following code, nothing is disabled in the dropdown.

Code for controller:

```
var editProject = this;

editProject.addMore = function() {

  editProject.project.fruit.push({});
};


editProject.fruitids = [

  {code: 'GOODS', fruit: '1. Apple'},
  {code: 'GOODS', fruit: '2. Orange'},
  {code: 'GOODS', fruit: '3. Peach'},
];
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in editProject.project.fruits">

  <select ng-model="editProject.project.fruits[$index]" 
ng-options="fruitid.class group by fruitid.code disable when (editProject.project.fruits.indexOf((fruitid)) !== -1) 
for fruitid in editProject.fruitids track by fruitid.class">

    <option value="">--Select Class--</option>

  </select>

</div>

<button ng-click="editProject.addMore()" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" role="button">Add More Classes
</button>
```

Comment: There's a missing bracket in your code : the `editProject.fruitids` array is not closed.

Comment: @LoremIpsum Fixed it. Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain what are the class options (i.e. what the options for each select input should be) ? Also, please separate HTML and JavaScript in your code snippets.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a function as the expression for the `disable` parameter in the `ng-options` directive.

Please see working [example1](https://jsfiddle.net/tjaart/v6qf0qju/)

HTML

```
 <div data-ng-repeat="item in items">
     <select data-ng-options="fruitId.fruit disable when isDisabled(fruitId) for fruitId in fruitIds" data-ng-model="items[$index]"></select>
  </div>
```

JS

```
$scope.isDisabled = function(fruitid) {
    return ($scope.items.indexOf((fruitid)) !== -1);
};
```

This will disable the `option` in **all** the `select`'s including the the `select` where the `option` was selected. The option will now not be selected any more as it is disabled.

You need to exclude the current `fruitId` so it is still enabled in the selected `select`

Please see [example2](https://jsfiddle.net/tjaart/v6qf0qju/1/) where the current `fruitId` is excluded and the selected `option` is disabled in the other `select`s

We make sure that the index found is not the index of the current item.

HTML

```
<div data-ng-repeat="item in items">
    <select data-ng-options="fruitId.fruit disable when isDisabled(fruitId, item) for fruitId in fruitIds" data-ng-model="items[$index]"></select>
</div>
```

JS

```
$scope.isDisabled = function(fruitid, item) {
    return ($scope.items.indexOf((fruitid)) !== -1 && $scope.items.indexOf((fruitid)) != $scope.items.indexOf(item));
};
```

Comment: For arrays : `label disable when disable for value in array track by trackexpr` For objects : `select as label disable when disable for (key, value) in object`

Answer (score 0):

This code can help to you?

index.html:

```
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <title>Demo</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/app.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
         <select ng-model="selectedOption" ng-change="change(selectedOption)">
         <option ng-repeat="var in myObj.myArr" value={{var.id}}  
                 ng-disabled="var.selectable">
                 {{var.fruit}}
         </option>
         </select>
         </div>
    </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
function AppCtrl ($scope) {

  $scope.myObj = {
    "myArr":[
      {id:0, code: 'GOODS', fruit: '1. Apple', selectable:false},
      {id:1, code: 'GOODS', fruit: '2. Orange', selectable:false},
      {id:2, code: 'GOODS', fruit: '3. Peach', selectable:false}
    ]};

  $scope.selectedOption = {};
  $scope.change = function(id){
    var name = $scope.myObj.myArr[id].selectable = true;
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can:

1- Create an angularjs directive that encapsulate every *select/dropdown* and assign a unique id to each of them.

2- Bind the array of elements to all directives

3- When the user selects an item you set an item's property (assignedTo) with the unique id of the directive as the value (and clean the property for all other items with this id as value)

4- The select disables elements based on the value of the property (assignedTo !== uniqueId)

View template:

```
<my-select-directive unique-select-id="1" items="theItems"><my-select-directive>

<my-select-directive unique-select-id="2" items="theItems"><my-select-directive>

<my-select-directive unique-select-id="3" items="theItems"><my-select-directive>
```

Directive template:

```
<select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-change="change()">
   <option ng-repeat="item in myItems" value={{item.id}}  
         ng-disabled="item.assignedTo && item.assignedTo !== uniqueSelectId">
        {{item.fruit}}
   </option>
</select>
```

Directive code:

```
//here you can implement logic to remember previous selection, now it doesn't
scope.selectedItem= null; 
scope.change = function(){
   //needed to sync
   //remove the mark of the previous selected item for this dropdown if any
   myItems.forEach(function(item) {if (item.assignedTo === scope.uniqueSelectId) item.assignedTo = null;});
   //now mark the item as selected in this dropdown
   selectedItem.assignedTo = scope.uniqueSelectId;  
}
```

This is not working code, it's only to guide you