# How to make dropdown to choose only one value using angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, drop-down-menu

I have dropdown in which options are coming from array using ng-repeat. It is working as normal drop-down. But I want in a different way. If one option is selected, it should be disabled in the other dropdowns. can we do like that in angular? I have some code already in plunker. But the problem is if we select one option and if we change that we are not able to select the previous option. That means, If we are selecting "Florida" in the first dropdown and "california" in second dropdown , then if we change the first drop down value to "Delaware", then we are not able to select all the three options in the dropdown.

Html code is:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="address in addresses">
        Billing State:
        <select
            ng-model="address.state"
            ng-options="state.lookupCode as state.description for state in lov_state"></select>
        <tt>State selected: {{address.state}}</tt>
    </div>

</div>
```

controller code is :

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.addresses = [
        {'state': 'AL'},
        {'state': 'CA'},
        {'state': 'FL'}
    ];

    $scope.lov_state = [
        {'lookupCode': 'AL', 'description': 'Alabama'},
        {'lookupCode': 'FL', 'description': 'Florida'},
        {'lookupCode': 'CA', 'description': 'California'},
        {'lookupCode': 'DE', 'description': 'Delaware'}
    ];
});
```

**[Demo Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/E0yu9XAxqjxpwArBfDbK?p=preview)**

Comment: Please see my answer on another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34377714/how-to-conditionally-disable-an-object-within-an-array-in-angular/34415783#34415783 I'm sure this is what you are after

Comment: Your question could do with clarifying.  Spell it out as a set of bullet points so we can replicate.  Use specific inputs and expected results.